# how to get desired output Mongodb sort query with group by

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Following is my mongodb collection having records like...

```
{"type":"ORDER_PLACE", "price":100, "emailId":"abcd1@gmail.com"}
{"type":"CART_ORDER", "price":150, "emailId":"abcd2@gmail.com"}
{"type":"ORDER_PLACE", "price":200, "emailId":"abcd1@gmail.com"}
{"type":"CART_ORDER", "price":350, "emailId":"abcd1@gmail.com"}
{"type":"CART_ORDER", "price":250, "emailId":"abcd2@gmail.com"}
{"type":"ORDER_PLACE", "price":240, "emailId":"abcd1@gmail.com"}
{"type":"ORDER_PLACE", "price":330, "emailId":"abcd2@gmail.com"}
```

I want the result should be like...

```
{"emailId":"abcd1@gmail.com", "type":"ORDER_PLACE", "total":540}
{"emailId":"abcd2@gmail.com", "type":"ORDER_PLACE", "total":330}
```

What will be the sort query to get the result like above(desc order).

Answer (score 0):

Here is query that gives you result in your structure:

```
db.coll.aggregate([{$match: {type: "ORDER_PLACE"}}, {$group: {_id: "$emailId", total: {$sum: "$price"}}},{$project:{_id:0,emailId:"$_id",type:"ORDER_PLACE",total:"$total"}}])
```